# Calculate response time for task closure

Tags: datetime, time

Please help me in the approach.

I have a task object and a field called task executioner.I want to have timer set on the record. When the user will edit the record the timer will start and when it is saved timer will stop and time difference need to be calculated.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to create a visualforce page to achieve it. But again multiple scenarios come here, like what should happen if user again clicks edit after saving. Should we add the response time to the previous value?.

Comment: For now lets add the response time to the previous value..

Comment: you have to create a visualforce page and override task new/edit buttons with this page. Then in the page you need to write logic to handle this.

Comment: Can u please provide me some logic to start with...

Comment: Create a field in the object to store value(Response_Time__c). Then in the constructor of the page, keep a variable to retrieve this value and assign to the variable. Also keep another variable time to save the time page loaded(constructor executed). Then in the save method add Response_TIme__c value with the difference of (saveTime - pageLoadTime)